# What are Wickerlings for?

Tags: yokus-island-express

I keep collecting these little guys called Wickerlings (I have two so far). Their tooltip says "These weird roots are said to spread good fortune wherever they're found".

What can I do with them? Unlike my Noisemaker and Kickback, I haven't figured out where these are useful yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look on the map for something that looks kind of like an old-fashioned lightpost. If you approach one and hit (A) when you have at least 10 Wickerlings I promise you won't miss what happens.